# center a div with background in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to center a text and a icon, but the icon is set in a background.

How to do to center the text and set the icon just on the left of the text.

Here is the fiddle and the code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RQfX/1/)

```
<div class="error divError" style="text-align: center">
            <p class="errorplaceholder">Error Text</p>
        </div>


.divError {
    background: url("https://www2.eiffel.com/download/images/warning_icon.png") no-repeat scroll left center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FF0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the p:

```
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0 0 0 'your_image_width'; 
background: url('you_image_url') left center no-repeat;
```

And the div:

```
text-align: center;
```

I think this should to the trick. If not, the idea is clear :).

Answer (score 2):

Set the image as a content of `before` pseudoelement of your paragraph.
Doing so you don't need to know in advance the width of your icon and set padding or make assumptions with percentages

```
.divError  {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
}

.divError p:before {
     content: url("https://www2.eiffel.com/download/images/warning_icon.png");
}
```

example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8RQfX/6/
Example with some extra code for a proper vertical-alignment): http://jsfiddle.net/8RQfX/6/

Comment: This is a good idea! Congratulations :). For someone looking for solution without 'conent:', try my answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

[fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/8RQfX/1/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="error divError" style="text-align: center">
        <p class="errorplaceholder">
            <img src="https://www2.eiffel.com/download/images/warning_icon.png" alt="1" /> <span>Error Text</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.divError {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I thought, that image must be ins CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
.divError {
background: url("https://www2.eiffel.com/download/images/warning_icon.png") no-repeat          scroll rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-position:45% 50%;
color: #FF0000;
font-weight: bold;
margin: auto;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use position percentages in the background-position attribute to get this done , if you insist that the icon should be as background image.

```
  background: url("https://www2.eiffel.com/download/images/warning_icon.png") no-repeat scroll 40% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

those values should do for you .

But I feel , it would be better if the icon is placed in a separate span.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc` property of css:

```
background-position:calc(50% - 40px) center;
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RQfX/7/

Comment: Not all browser friendly, but definetely the best answer in my opinion. +1.

Comment: if text increases it does not auto adjust.

Comment: this requires to know in advance the width of the icon. not really scalable

Comment: Yeah, they are right. But for me still +1 for calc. Looking for something like this for ages :).

Comment: Of-course it won't. This is problem specific answer, not a generic solution at all. Also, this is not a generic problem. Ideally, that image should not be in background if text is centre-aligned and width is not fixed.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan has a good idea with :before. My answer is multi browser friendly, but needs also the constant width of icon. Best regards. Calc, amazing :).

Comment: @Jacek: It looks like you are very excited with `calc`. It really works great when you have to do calculations without javascript. I have used in many times when I dont care about IE8. :P

Comment: Yeah, really I was dreaming about calc since 3 years, and You are the one that enlighten me with it. I own You a beer :). Now we must look forward to the ages, when every browser know that trick. Thx a lot :).

Comment: congratulation!! you got what you were looking from a log time!!